# Thymeleaf + Spring Boot - how to create form for object with Map field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How should I create an html form to bind data with Map field in my DTO object?
Here is my DTO class:

```
@Data
public class SimpleBTO {
    private String field1;
    private Map<String,Integer> mapField;
}
```

So once again, how to create a form in thymeleaf for such element?

Comment: Try googling "Thymeleaf Map Form" Also see, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915358/thymeleaf-map-form-binding

Answer (score 0):

If you know the keys:

```
<form th:object="${dto}">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{mapField['key']}" />
</form>
```

Similarly, you can loop over all the values:

```
<form th:object="${dto}">
  <input th:each="entry: ${dto.mapField}" type="text" th:field="*{mapField['__${entry.key}__']}" />
</form>
```

Comment: And what if i don't know they keys/ want to add new entries?

Comment: @tomektomek -- works the same way... the two examples above work regardless of whether they already exist in the map or not (except in the second example, `${entry.key}` would instead be an expression that resolves to the string key of the entry you want to save.